# Using Volley in Android Studio with a Json file that has a link to another Json file that i want to get the data from

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I managed to show the data from a Json file with Volley in RecycleView. The line that says "photo = finalLink.getString("href");" is a link to another Json file. I don't want to show the link. I want to show the data that there are in that Json file. How do i do that?

https://psaddict.gr/wp-json <--- This is the first Json file. And there is a link to another Json file that goes to varius json file and I want to get the data from these json files for example https://psaddict.gr/wp-json/wp/v2/media

```
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    final JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject mmname = jsonObject.getJSONObject("title");
                    JSONObject explain = jsonObject.getJSONObject("excerpt");
                    JSONObject mmlinks = jsonObject.getJSONObject("_links");
                    JSONArray lllinks = mmlinks.getJSONArray("wp:featuredmedia");
                    JSONObject finalLink = lllinks.getJSONObject(0);
                    photo = finalLink.getString("href");

                    Model model = new Model();
                    model.setTitle(mmname.getString("rendered"));
                    model.setReference(explain.getString("rendered"));
                    model.setTest(finalLink.getString("href"));




                    modelList.add(model);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("Volley", error.toString());

        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

Comment: Please give your json details

Comment: What is href is a link.?? post your response fully so we can help you friend

Comment: What do you want to do with that json received from that link? Just display it as json or do something similar to recyclerview?

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: share your json file data format .